# Likes on Video Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, video

I want to add likes to the videos i upload using JW player.
Is there any built in function in SharePoint 2013?
Pl help.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you'll want to add a bit more detail to your question, if you want to increase your chances. Also, it's good to add links to any 3rd party tools you might be using.

Comment: @TiagoDuarte: I am using JW player for playing the video that i upload on SP 2013. Now I want to add functionality that will allow my users to like the video I upload, like one we do in Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Social integration is usually based on provider [plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins).

You can also check the 3rd party [documentation on Social Sharing](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1409823-social-sharing-overlay).

See more on:

[Integrating social media with public-facing websites in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/07/04/integrating-social-media-with-public-facing-websites-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)